# Oracle multiset, collection and records

Tags: sql, oracle, collections, records, multiset

Can anybody explain to me why records are required?  Can't we just perform the same operation in PL/SQL using loop.  Also when can a multiset record query can be used?   i.e. in which type of situation and which one would be the preference?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a great link on this topic:
http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/03-sep/o53plsql.html

Read the part about "Set Theory and Multiset Union".

It more or less works like `UNION ALL`, with one important difference:

> "Unlike the SQL UNION set operator,
>   the collection MULTISET UNION operator
>   does **not** reorder the elements in the
>   resulting collection. MULTISET UNION
>   preserves the order in each collection
>   and simply appends the contents of the
>   second after the first. ".

Comment: It seems to be not available any more.

Comment: Current URL for article: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/o53plsql-083350.html